# How do I switch from Unity 8 in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: 16.10

When I turn on my computer running Ubuntu 16.10, I only see my name with the Unity 8 symbol.

[image]

When I type the password it directs me to Unity 8 desktop environment.

[image]

How can I return to the regular Ubuntu desktop environment?

Comment: Additional to the answers, really make sure when trying Unity 8 that you have *automatic login disabled*, otherwise you need to manually edit lightdm's config files to switch back to your normal desktop environment again, because the current Unity 8 preview still lacks a logout button. Been there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click the Unity 8 symbol, and you'll get a list of installed DEs, for example:

[image]

From there you can select your preferred DE.

Comment: DE = desktop environment?

Comment: @TomHart - Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the little 8 in the login screen and select Ubuntu (Default). Then log in line you always do and you're back at Unity 7.